# replacing/rewriting inside existential hypothesis

Tags: coq

I have the following proof state:

```
H: exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x l
----------------------
Goal: exists x0 : A, f x0 = y /\ In x0 (x :: l)
```

I know that `In x l` implies `In x (x :: l)`. So I'd like to finish off the proof with a rewrite something like this:

```
rewrite ___ in H.
```

leading to the proof state:

```
H: exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x (x :: l)
----------------------
Goal: exists x0 : A, f x0 = y /\ In x0 (x :: l)
```

Which can be completed (I think) with:

```
exact H.
```

Is such a rewrite possible? Is there a valid technique I can use along these lines?

`rewrite` fails and `replace` in the hypothesis doesn't seem to actually change the hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After destructing the hypothesis to get `f x = y /\ In x l`, we can do setoid rewriting using `in_cons : In x l -> In x (x' :: l)` (from the `List` module) but with a bit of extra work.

We somehow have to first beta-expand the lemma to `in_cons : impl (In x l) (In x (x' :: l))` (below, using the `fold` tactic), so it gets recognized as a rewrite rule (`impl` is registered as a rewriting relation, whereas `->` is sugar for primitive syntax, that's not recognized by the rewriting plugin).

As far as I can tell, it's not possible to rewrite while the `exists` is there, even with the `setoid_rewrite` variant that works under binders in the right situations.

```
Require Import List.

Lemma foo {A B} (f : A -> B) (x' : A) (y : B) (l : list A)
  (H: exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x l) :
exists x0 : A, f x0 = y /\ In x0 (x' :: l).
Proof.
  destruct H.
  pose proof (in_cons x' x l) as E.
  fold (Basics.impl (In x l) (In x (x' :: l))) in E.
  rewrite E in H.
  eauto.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation is incredibly helpful. I removed the import of Setoid.Morphisms, didn't seem to be needed in Coq v8.11.1.

Comment: I want to check my understanding so I can know how to approach problems like this next time. It seems like either (A) I was doing something weird or (B) `fold`ing `impl` is a really common thing to do. Or is there an option C?

Comment: I'm hesitating between A and C. I've never seen anyone actually folding `impl`, but I could imagine it being useful sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

No, such rewrite is not possible, as far as I know.

But you might want to try `destruct H as [x H]. exists x.`.
This will give you `x` that satisfies `f x = y /\ In x 1`.

Comment: Thanks - `destruct H` turned out to be necessary. Believe it or not, I'd forgotten how to break apart an existential hypothesis! But the rewrite (as described in another answer) https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043782/2482570 is the only way we've found so far to go the final step to  `In x (x' :: l)`. There's almost certainly another way, though.